# Adapt Excel to have children to parse to json?

Tags: json, excel, csv, parsing

I have an excel file filled with data that i must parse to a json file.
But when i coded the program i did this structure.

```
"wasdsadas" : {
    "asignatura" : 6,
    "nivel" : 2,
    "unidad" : [ [ {
      "OA" : 1,
      "indicadores" : [ "Testing", "testeo2" ],
      "objetivo" : "Testeo"
    } ], [ {
      "OA" : 2,
      "indicadores" : [ "testing", "testeo2" ],
      "objetivo" : "testeo 2"
    } ] ]
  }
```

Is there a way to adapt the csv made from the excel to parse a json like that?

Im using this converter: [csv2json](http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json)

Comment: It is a way. Can you post an example of the csv?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NiBpe Something like this.

Comment: You can adapt this code: https://codingislove.com/json-csv/